# Matlab forecasting with autoregressive exogenous modell

Tags: matlab, forecasting, autoregressive-models

i have a file, which is the energy consumption of a house. 
every 10 minute one value (watt):

```
10:00 123
10:10 125
10:20 0
...
```

It means each day have 144 value (Rows). 
i want to forecast the energy of the next day with ARX an ARMAX programm. i did write ARX code in Matlab. but i can't forecast the next day. My code take the last 5 consumption and forecast the 6th one. How can i forecast the nex 144 value ( = the day after)

```
% ARX Process----------------------------
L=length(u_in)
u_in_ID=u_in;% Input data used for Identification
u_in_vfy=u_in;% Input data used for verification

y_out_ID=y_out;% Output data used for Identification
y_out_vfy=y_out;%Output data used for verification
m=5; %Parameter to be used to generate order of delay for Input, Output and Error
n=length(y_out_ID)-m;
I=eye(n,1)+1;
I(1)=I(1)-1;
A=I; % Initialize Matrix A
Y=y_out_ID((m+1):end); % Defining Y vector
length(Y)
na=1;
% Put output delay 1 to m-na in A matrix
for k=1:1:m-na
    A=[A y_out_ID((m-k+1):(end-k))];
end
% Put "Current Input -- mth delayed Input" to Matrix A
for p=1:1:m
    k=p-1;
    A=[A u_in_ID((m-k+1):(end-k))];
end
A(:,1)=[]; % Delete 1st column of Matrix A, which was used to Initialize it
parsol=inv(A'*A)*A'*Y;
BB=A*parsol;
% Generate Identified Output vector based on previous
% outputs, current and previous Inputs and Parameters solved by Least
% square method
n=length(y_out_vfy)-m;
I=eye(n,1)+1;
I(1)=I(1)-1; 
A=I;
for k=1:1:m-na
    A=[A y_out_vfy((m-k+1):(end-k))];
end

for p=1:1:m
    k=p-1;
    A=[A u_in_vfy((m-k+1):(end-k))];
end
A(:,1)=[]; % Delete 1st column of Matrix A, which was used to Initialize it
A;
y_out_sysID=A*parsol;
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this question still alive?

Comment: for next 144 values do the same, means cal the value from previous 5 vals